# Querying a JavaScript object with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a JavaScript object like:

```
var people = {
    items: [
        { id: "1", name: "j", age: "11", gender: "m"},
        { id: "2", name: "k", age: "22", gender: "f"},
        { id: "3", name: "l", age: "33", gender: "m"},
        { id: "4", name: "m", age: "44", gender: "f"},
        { id: "5", name: "n", age: "55", gender: "m"}
    ]
};
```

Is there a way I can retrieve a single "record"? And what data type would it need to be?

If I want the 'age' and 'gender' of (id=4 and name=m), how can I do that?

I know this design might not be ideal, but I am thinking in LINQ, and the data sets won't be huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var personID4 =  people.items.filter(function(person)
{ 
    return person.id === "4";
});
```

or

```
var personID4 =  people.items.filter(function(person)
{ 
    return person.name === "m"; 
});
```

or what you need a combination:

```
var personID4 =  people.items.filter(function(person)
{ 
    return person.id === "4" && person.name === "m"; 
});
```

**Important:**
It is recommended to use "===" instead of "==" because 5 is not equal to "5". Double equal will evaluate this as true, if that is your case then you can use "==".

Additionally this works on IE9+ if you need this to run in IE8 or ealier please follow the polyfill instructions in this link :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to Linq, you should look at the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods, (which are roughly equivalent to the Linq `Where` and `Select` methods, respectively):

```
var person = people.items
    .filter(function(x) { return x.id == "4" && x.name == "m"; })
    .map(function(x) { return { age: x.age, gender: x.gender }; })[0];
```

But this was introduced in ES5, so it won't be available on some older browsers. If this is a concern, you'd have to use a plain old `for`-loop:

```
var person;
for (var i = 0; i < people.items.length; i++)
{
    if (people.items[i].id == "4" && people.items[i].name == "m")
    {
        person = { age: people.items[i].age, gender: people.items[i].gender };
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return { x.age, x.gender };` ? Did you mean to use an array?

Comment: @FelixKling No, sorry I was thinking of C#, where property names are automatic on anonymous types.

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PY2um/7/)

```
function getPeopleById(id){
    for(var i=0; i< people.items.length; i++){
        if(people.items[i].id == id){
            return people.items[i];
        }
    }
}

alert(getPeopleById(4).name)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to reuse your LINQ habits would be to use linq.js

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

The code for this particular case is

```
Enumerable.From( people.items )
   .Where( function(x) { return x.id == "4" && x.name == "m" } )
   .ToArray();
```

or even

```
Enumerable.From( people.items )
   .Where( 'x => x.id == "4" && x.name == "m"' )
   .ToArray();
```

As a side effect of using this library, you can use other LINQ operators already known to you.

> > Is there a way I can retrieve a single "record"? And what data type would it need to be?

There is no notion of "data type" in Javascript or rather, there is but not in a sense you probably would like it to be. You just get a set/list/array of objects which share common properties.